# Can I customize escape feature?

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to escape the single quote ' to '' for t-sql. Is it possible? Can I customize the default output format HTML? Or can I write a CustomOutputFormat class? Or does freemarker have other features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom `MarkupOutputFormat`, with your own escaping rules, yes. Though SQL is not really markup... but, it still works. Though, you have mention HTML output, so I'm not sure what the actual output format will be.